# do I need a linux server to deploy a mean stack application?

Tags: web-applications, mean-stack

This might seem like a dumb question but is it possible to deploy a MEAN stack application on a machine running windows ? or is it only possible with a linux machine

note: and by deploy, I mean use it in a production environment that people on an outside network would be able to access

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use the MEAN stack on windows. There are a couple of different ways:

1. Just run the app using the command line from a windows server.
2. Package the app as a windows service using [node-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows). This will give you a real .exe file.

You'll have to go to the windows firewall settings and allow incoming traffic on whatever port you are exposing.

Here's a link to a post on the topic : http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2015/12/26/setup-the-mean-stack-on-windows